# Tecno BC3 failing to push notifications

Tags: push-notifications, background-process

Notification features not available
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54iih.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54iih.png)

Comment: Tecno BC3 runs Android 10 Go, which is covered in the duplicate question.